# SQLAlchemy Python 3 Async Database Circular Import with separate Models file

Tags: python, postgresql, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

Been trying to get SQLAlchemy setup Async to work with a Postgres Database -- I've been following multiple tutorials but the main one I was using was this one [SQLAlchemy Async ORM IS Finally Here](https://ahmed-nafies.medium.com/sqlalchemy-async-orm-is-finally-here-d560dfaa335d)

In it he uses a `models.py` file with Class Methods for `create`, `update`, and `get`, and I really like that so I was trying to follow along, but I'm getting a circular import between my `database.py` file and my `models.py` file and I'm unsure how to fix it as the `models.py` relies on the Async DB sessions + Base from `database.py` and `database.py` relies on the class methods to update, get, create data. I'm probably being lazy or silly and missing something but I would appreciate any help

Realistically my end goal is just to get a nicely setup database for creating, updating, getting, that's really all I need and I'm trying to navigate this but not many people seem to know about SQLAlchemy and Async

`models.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, BigInteger, String, Float, DateTime, func, ForeignKey, Boolean
from sqlalchemy import update as sqlalchemy_update
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from helpers.database import async_db, Base


class ModelAdmin:
    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, **kwargs):
        session = await async_db.get_session()
        session.add(cls(**kwargs))
        await session.commit()

    @classmethod
    async def update(cls, id, **kwargs):
        query = (
            sqlalchemy_update(cls)
            .where(cls.id == id)
            .values(**kwargs)
            .execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
        )
        session = await async_db.get_session()
        await session.execute(query)
        await session.commit()

    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, id):
        query = select(cls).where(cls.id == id)
        session = await async_db.get_session()
        results = await session.execute(query)
        (result,) = results.one()
        return result


class Employee(Base, ModelAdmin):
    __tablename__ = "employees"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(100))
    displayname = Column(String(100))
    email = Column(String(100), default="")
    emp_type = Column(String(30), default="")
    team = Column(String(100), default="")
    redline = Column(Float, default=-1)
    tier = Column(Integer, default=-1)
    cur_kw = Column(Float, default=0.0)
    emp_over = Column(BigInteger, default=-1)
    emp_under = Column(String, default="")
    deals = relationship("Deal")
    __mapper_args__ = {"eager_defaults": True}

    def get_tier(self) -> int:
        return .2

    def set_tier(self, tier: int) -> None:
        if self.emp_type == "canvasser":
            self.tier = tier

    def add_emp_over(self, emp):
        '''Adds an employee OVER another, AKA makes them a parent of the employee'''
        if emp.id not in self.emp_over.keys():
            self.emp_over[emp.id] = emp
            return f"Added {emp.username} as parent of {self.username}"

    def add_emp_under(self, emp):
        '''Adds an employee UNDER another, AKA makes them a child of the employee'''
        if emp.id not in self.emp_under.keys():
            self.emp_under[emp.id] = emp


class Deal(Base, ModelAdmin):
    __tablename__ = "deals"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    closer_id = Column(ForeignKey("employees.id"))
    deal_size = Column(Float)
    ppw = Column(Float)
    dealer_fee = Column(Float)
    lead_owner = relationship("Employee")
    installed = Column(Boolean)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())

    def get_commission(self):
        '''
            Gets the commission from this deal for the closer and the canvasser if the canvasser is set (otherwise it's a self-gen)
        '''
        commission = 0
        if not self.canvasser:
            commission = (self.deal_size * 1000) * \
                ((self.ppw * self.dealer_fee) - self.closer.blueline)
            return {commission}
        else:
            commission = {(self.deal_size * 1000) *
                          ((self.ppw * self.dealer_fee) - self.closer.blueline)}
            commission[1] = commission[0] * self.canvasser.getTier()
            commission[0] = commission[0] - commission[1]
            return commission
```

`database.py`

```py
import discord
import asyncpg
import os
import json
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from helpers.configuration import Config

load_dotenv()

db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
db_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
db_pass = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
db_host = os.environ.get('DB_URL')


Base = declarative_base()


class AsyncDatabaseSession:
    '''Handles database connections, updates the employee list, receives member role updates, that good stuff'''
    from helpers.models import Employee

    def __init__(self):
        # here we should connect to and setup the database (if not setup) as well as
        # scan and index all members into Employee's then keep their database counterpart updated as well
        # any role updates should also ping here, let's get it
        self.employee_list = {}
        self._session = None
        self._engine = None

    async def init(self):
        self._engine = create_async_engine(
            f'postgresql+asyncpg://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}/{db_name}',
            echo=True,
            future=True
        )

        self._session = sessionmaker(
            self._engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
        )

    async def create_all(self):
        async with self._engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    async def async_session_generator(self):
        return sessionmaker(
            self._engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_1=AsyncSession
        )

    async def get_session(self):
        try:
            async_session = await self.async_session_generator()

            async with async_session() as session:
                yield session
        except:
            await session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            await session.close()
    
    async def update_employee(self, user: Employee):
        """Updates an employee"""
        from helpers.models import Employee
        if not len(user.emp_under) > 0:
            await Employee.update(
                id=user.user_id, username=user.username, displayname=user.displayname, email=user.email,
                emp_type=user.emp_type, team=user.team, redline=user.redline, tier=user.tier, cur_kw=user.cur_kw,
                emp_over=user.emp_over
            )
        else:
            await Employee.update(
                id=user.user_id, username=user.username, displayname=user.displayname, email=user.email,
                emp_type=user.emp_type, redline=user.redline, tier=user.tier, cur_kw=user.cur_kw,
                emp_over=user.emp_over, emp_under=json.dumps(user.emp_under)
            )

async_db = AsyncDatabaseSession()
```

Comment: I think this is more of a python problem rather than asyncio.  I would move `update_employee` into models somewhere or even into another `services.py` file.

Comment: Also probably move `ModelAdmin` either into its own file or back into `database.py`.

Comment: Okay I'll try that out and report back!